# Use diff -u to show the difference between two files

Tags: linux, diff

I'm trying to understand how to use diff -u to make two files the same.

I did: `diff -x .git -u -r ../company1-merlin/group_vars/accounts  group_vars/accounts`

And got back this result:

```
    --- ../company1-dev-merlin/group_vars/accounts  2020-09-23 09:48:04.963021338 -0400
    +++ group_vars/accounts 2020-09-23 10:08:02.036869362 -0400
@@ -62,3 +62,4 @@
     output_path: /etc/filebeat-sip/filebeat-sip-STATECHANGE
     field_delimiter: ";"
     field_mapping: '["timestamp","eventType","id","type","state"]'
+
```

Does it mean that in the second file there are 4 lines after line 62 and in the first file there are 3 lines?

What does `@@ -62,3 +62,4 @@` mean? What has to change to make these files the same?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/understanding-of-diff-output To apply a diff see `man patch`.

Comment: The program for making two files the same is `cp`.  In the above, it looks like the second file has an additional blank line.